# Typescript tuple spread type

Tags: typescript

What is the purpose and meaning of defining a type like this..?
`type AccountDetails1 = [AccountDetails, ...AccountDetails[]];`

Is it equivalent to this union type..?
`type AccountDetails2 = AccountDetails | AccountDetails[];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that an array with the type of `AccountDetails1` must be an array of `AccountDetails` with a minimum length of 1. The first part of the tuple indicates that the first element in the array must be of type `AccountDetails`, and the second part of the tuple means that the array may contain zero or more `AccountDetails` item in the array.

In short:

```
type AccountDetails1 = [AccountDetails, ...AccountDetails[]];

const arr1: AccountDetails1 = [AccountDetails]; // OK
const arr2: AccountDetails1 = [AccountDetails, AccountDetails]; // OK
const arr3: AccountDetails1 = []; // ERROR
```

In other words, `type AccountDetails2 = AccountDetails | AccountDetails[];` means that it can be either of type `AccountDetails` *or* an array of `AccountDetails` with zero or more members:

```
type AccountDetails2 = AccountDetails | AccountDetails[];

const arr1: AccountDetails2 = [AccountDetails]; // OK
const arr2: AccountDetails2 = [AccountDetails, AccountDetails]; // OK
const arr3: AccountDetails2 = []; // OK
const obj1: AccountDetails2 = AccountDetails; // OK
```

Comment: Indeed. It's worth noting that the syntax allows for heterogeneous array types

Comment: OK, so the main difference is that 2 allows for an empty array, but 1 does not? That's neat!

Answer (score 1):

```
type AccountDetails1 = [AccountDetails, ...AccountDetails[]];
```

It means that variables from type *AccountDetails1* must be an array of AccountDetails, and

```
type AccountDetails2 = AccountDetails | AccountDetails[];
```

Can be either an *AccountDetails* or an array of AccountDetails